# Issues while interfacing R with GRASS GIS using rgrass package

Tags: r-sf, proj, grass

I want to use some GRASS-GIS tools in R and I am using the `rgrass` package to interface R to GRASS GIS installed on my windows machine.
When I run `initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/Program Files/GRASS GIS 8.2", home = tempdir())` to initialize the environment, I get a warning with the message;

```
Warning message:
In system(syscmd, intern = intern, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr,  :
  running command 'g.proj.exe -w' had status 1
```

I am using GRASS GIS version `8.2`. I have installed `PROJ` version `9.2` separately and set the `PROJ_DATA` environment variable to the value of `C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj`. I am running out of options now. What could be the cause of this?

I have consulted these threads [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377481/unable-to-execute-grass-7-8-in-rstudio) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351637/problem-running-grass-with-r) but they refer to the older `rgrass7` package which is now broken. Documentation to the newer `rgrass` package seems sparse.

Comment: With the help of `@rsbivand ` (Roger Bivand), the root cause of this problem has been narrowed down to the difference between the `proj.db` database used by current version of `terra` and `WinGRASS 8.2`. I am trying now to downgrade my installed `terra` to see how it goes.